# How to add javascript to theme_preprocess_user_login

Tags: javascript, theming, forms

I have working code in my theme's template.php file that adds "autofocus" to my modal login form, but Firefox ignores ajax autofocus fields ([only applies autofocus on pageload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955398/autofocus-attribute-of-html5-does-not-work-only-in-firefox-when-forminput-ar)). So I'm trying to add some js to set focus when the modal login form is called. I currently add autofocus via:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_user_login(&$variables) {
  $variables['form']['name']['#attributes']['autofocus'] = array('autofocus');
  $variables['rendered'] = drupal_render_children($variables['form']);
}
```

And I'm trying to add js to set focus as a fallback this way:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_user_login(&$variables) {
  $variables['form']['name']['#attributes']['autofocus'] = array('autofocus');
  $variables['form']['#attached'][js][] = path_to_theme() . "/js/focus.js";
  $variables['rendered'] = drupal_render_children($variables['form']);
}
```

but this doesn't seem to add the js as expected. How can I add either inline or external javascript to my modal login form?

Answer (score 1):

A preferred solution I would use for adding/editing forms would be to use a module hook.

```
function MODULE_form_user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  $form['#attached']['js'] = array(
    drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME') . '/js/focus.js',
    '/* inline js here */' => array( 'type' => 'inline')
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get any of the dynamic insertion of javascript to work at all, so I ended up adding the following to my site-wide javascript file:

```
$(document).delegate(
  'form#user-login', 
  'DOMNodeInserted', 
  function(){ $('input#edit-name').focus();
});
```

This is, of course, wrapped in the proper `(function ($) { Drupal.behaviors.mytheme = { ...` namespacing, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Use the standard drupal_add_js https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME') .'/js/focus.js', 'file');
drupal_add_js('(function ($) { ... })(jQuery);', array('type' => 'inline', 'group' => JS_THEME));
```

Comment: This does not seem to actually attach any javascript via preprocess hook.

Comment: To be fair I wasn't too sure myself.  I tried it too and I couldn't get it to work.